# document.ready is not working for newly created elements in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datepicker

Following is my `jQuery` code in the controller which is working fine for the input elements which created when template loads. Now the problem is, I have a drop down and on the basis of option select I am showing a input box for date, however the datepicker is not showing in this case.

Let me know what I need to do in this case. I tried and found some solution regarding `directive` implementation but I am not a seasoned and don't know whether it will going to solve my problem or not.

My jQuery code in the controller -

```
angular.module("app").controller("myCtrl", function($scope, userService, $http) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /****  Datepicker  ****/
        if ($('.datepicker').length && $.fn.datepicker) {
            $('.datepicker').each(function () {
                var datepicker_inline = $(this).data('inline') ? $(this).data('inline') : false;
                $(this).datepicker({
                    inline: datepicker_inline,
                    formatDate:'Y-m-d'
                });
            });
        }

        /****  Datetimepicker  ****/
        if ($('.datetimepicker').length && $.fn.datetimepicker) {
            $('.datetimepicker').each(function () {
                var datetimepicker_inline = $(this).data('inline') ? $(this).data('inline') : false;
                $(this).datetimepicker({
                    inline: datetimepicker_inline,
                    formatDate:'Y-m-d'
                });
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: in angularjs the way to handle it is to use directives like [ui-date](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date)

Comment: Could you please share your html code also.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I posted my solution ..though I will dig into the directives for more concrete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `ng-show`.

Initially I was using `ng-if` which was creating elements dynamically but I changed this with `ng-show` like -

```
.form-group(ng-if="event.repeat === 2")
```

TO

```
.form-group(ng-show="event.repeat === 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code doesn't belong to the controller, it doesn't have to be there in the first place. Please bear in mind that angular and jQuery plugins can coexist, every project is different.
It's hard to have an opinion as I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but that should make it work:

```
angular.module("app").controller("myCtrl", function($scope, userService, $http) {

 //... controller's logic here

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    /****  Datepicker  ****/
    if ($('.datepicker').length && $.fn.datepicker) {
        $('.datepicker').each(function () {
            var datepicker_inline = $(this).data('inline') ? $(this).data('inline') : false;
            $(this).datepicker({
                inline: datepicker_inline,
                formatDate:'Y-m-d'
            });
        });
    }

    /****  Datetimepicker  ****/
    if ($('.datetimepicker').length && $.fn.datetimepicker) {
        $('.datetimepicker').each(function () {
            var datetimepicker_inline = $(this).data('inline') ? $(this).data('inline') : false;
            $(this).datetimepicker({
                inline: datetimepicker_inline,
                formatDate:'Y-m-d'
            });
        });
    }
});
```